# How do I define a Go type constraint that's either a map or a slice?

Tags: go, generics

I'm trying to define a type constraint where it accepts either a `[]T` or `map[any]T`, i.e. either a slice or a map with the same element value. The use case for this is specifically implementing a `First` function, that returns the first element from a collection.

This is my attempt, which is not working:

```golang
type collection[Value any] interface {
    []Value | map[any]Value
}

func first[Value any, Coll collection[Value]](coll Coll) (Value, bool) {
    for _, value := range coll {
        return value, true
    }

    var empty Value
    return empty, false
}
```

Is this even possible? I might be running into limitations of what type constraints can, at the current time *(Go 1.18)*.

A Go playground for this can be found [here](https://goplay.tools/snippet/nUH2KCWuG3S).

Comment: it's possible if in the function body you do basically nothing with `T`. If you `make`, `range`, index with `[]` or whatever specific operation that would work on slices and maps *separately*, it won't work, because the constraint doesn't have a core type

Comment: on a side note, indexing wouldn't work anyway with `[]T` and `map[any]T` because the type of the index would differ: `int` for the slice and exactly `any` for the map

Comment: Examples: https://go.dev/play/p/8TDZeUVUlg3